# how to handle the following using kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

suppose I have the following situation

```
producer sends the following instructions on to kafka : 
1. "debit 100 from account A"
2. "send email to user A that his account is debited by 100"
and there is a consumer that does the following :
1. does the actual work of 'debit 100'
2. does the actual work of 'sending mail'
```

say, consumer instance crashed and I brought up another instance.
Now, consumer tells kafka to 'replay' (to materialize its view of the data)
As far as the real world is concerned, the consumer should not be acting on those instructions (which will lead to uncalled for debit and email), but, just read the data and do whatever it needs to materialize its view.

Question is, how does consumer know it had "acted" on a message earlier, so, should not re-act on it. It just needs to capture the message-status info internally ?

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can do is to have your consumer manually commit offsets. For this you need to change the default consumer config `enable.auto.commit` from `true` to `false`. Then, in your consumer application, after you successfully acted on a message you commit the offset.